# JavaScript variable scope - proper use

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I read this [style guide for angular](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide) from johnpapa. There is a snippet:

```
/*
 * recommend
 * Using function declarations
 * and bindable members up top.
 */
function Avengers(dataservice, logger) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.avengers = [];
    vm.getAvengers = getAvengers;
    vm.title = 'Avengers';

    activate();

    function activate() {
        return getAvengers().then(function() {
            logger.info('Activated Avengers View');
        });
    }

    function getAvengers() {
        return dataservice.getAvengers().then(function(data) {
            vm.avengers = data;
            return vm.avengers;
        });
    }
}
```

So my question is in functions `activate()` and `getAvengers()`, they both reference variable (`dataservice`) and function (`getAvengers()`) outside of their scope. Is this proper use? Should I bind these 2 in the variable `vm` instead, e.g:

```
vm.getAvengers = getAvengers; 
vm.dataservice = dataservice;
...
function activate() {
    return vm.getAvengers().then(....);
}

function getAvengers() {
    return vm.dataservice.getAvengers().then(.....);
}
```

Comment: Well, doing that doesn't change a thing, since now they both reference the variable `vm` outside of their scope. Anyway, it IS proper use of the language and it has actually nothing to do with angularjs. I recommend you look for more information about closures in JavaScript. It's amongst the basics of the language.

Comment: @jlowcs Think the question has more to do with design rather than if the code works or not, and think adding the angular tag gives insight into the available mechanisms in the environment (i.e. DI is available and should be used, explicit ways you should register services and shared constants, etc) which would greatly effect the recommended design of the code

Comment: Fair enough. That would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Specifically for your case

Would say if you are meaning to use this within angular app would recommend not exposing the service, exposing it through this object does not add value and might down the road, when a less experienced developer modifies your code, might result in wonky access to shared dependencies.

If you want access to the `dataservice` objects functionality across multiple entities then register it as an angular service, and inject it to the different entities that need it.

#### In General

Both of the ways you are describing are perfectly correct use, but as is usually the case the answer which to use is "it depends."

Why you would use one for another would be if you wanted to expose the variable externally (i.e. if you wanted to let others access that object through the returned object, expecting others to dynamically change the service on your object)

So in this example you should ask yourself a few question

1. Do I want to expose this object through another object or do I want to let angular DI pass this along to the other controllers that need this functionality
2. Do I want to allow external entities to modify this object
3. Does exposing this service through my object make the use of the perceived use of this object more confusing?

But again for **this particular case** you should not expose it through your object ( through your variable `vm`, which is bound to the return object `this`, in this case )

Answer (score -1):

The vm is a acronym for a view model (a object representation of your view) it is meant to be used within your view to bind elements, ui events to it. The dataservice and the logger seems to nothing to do with the view at all, they are just services used within a controller. If you assign them to the vm then you probably create a tightly coupling between your view and services thus it seems like a not a very good idea to me. You can think about the VM as a interface (glue) between your view and controller.

Here is a picture of the interactions between view model, controller, view and services.

[image]